# CSS 3 gradient doesn't work in ie 8

Tags: css, css3pie

I have a CSS3 `gradient` button that works everywhere except IE8.

I'm using [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for IE8.

See the search button in action here: http://whygo.net/

I'm seeing an error in my console on the line:

```
PIE.htc, line 94 character 103
```

which is :

```
var a=window.PIE
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this tool it will work in IE8 no problem:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/